# angularjs: ng-model onwatch only triggers once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use filtering and sorting with Angularjs, but my filter only fires once.
I have looked at alot of other samples but it is not clear to me why this only fires once.

HTML

```
Search: <input ng-model="query.$">
From: <input ng-model="query.From">
DepartureTime: <input ng-model="query.DepartureTime">
```

JS
    $scope.$watch('query', function (newValue, oldValue) { /* */ }

http://jsfiddle.net/E4V7X/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deep watch `query` since you're looking for changes in it's child properties, you do that by passing true as the third argument of `$watch`

```
$scope.$watch('query', function (newValue, oldValue) {
//
},true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great tip, it works now. Missed this in the manual dough :-$

Comment: Is it normal that the watch is not getting triggered by the search.$?